# What does newing an empty struct do in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, clr

If you have declared a struct:

```
struct EmptyResult
{
}
```

What is the result of creating a variable of type `EmptyResult` in an instance?

```
public Foo()
{
    EmptyResult result;
}
```

Would you expect an allocation on the stack, or is it effectively a no-op?

Comment: I would hope the compiler optimizes this. Put a break point on that line in Foo and see if its hit?

Comment: It would be optimised away if you made the variable of type `int`. Perhaps a better example would involve passing the struct to a function.

Comment: Which makes me wonder, where is the type of value and reference types stored but, that is a different question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C# compiler forces an empty struct to have a size of 1 byte. You can see this if you have a look at the struct in a decompiler:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size=1)]
private struct EmptyResult
{
}
```

So any instance of that struct in a class or on the stack will occupy 1 byte, exactly the same as an instance of `System.Byte` or `System.SByte`

Comment: Presumably it does so in order to be able to take its address.

Comment: You don't need to decompile. You can use `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(EmptyResult))`. Which I was just about to post, but was too slow.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sure you're right - it's so you can take its address, but also so that two instances will have different addresses. Interestingly, [Stroustrup mentions that about empty C++ structs](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty).

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I think C# has this behavior because C++ does, even though C# generally doesn't use addresses as object identifiers the way C++ does.

Answer (score 3):

A C# struct with no fields still has a size of 1. The reason this is so is that the compiler must be able to take the address of a struct using the `&` operator in unsafe code.

I would expect your struct type to be treated exactly the same way as the `byte` type.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a stack allocation, which is in line with how non-reference types work.

Comment: But the size of the struct is 0 bytes; how do you allocate 0 bytes?

Comment: In c++, it takes up one byte.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `idlasm.exe` to study the il, at the line which you create an instance of the `Empty` struct, you'll see:

```
.maxstack  1
.locals init ([0] valuetype Draft.Empty e)
```

And the definition of `Empty` struct is:

```
.class private sequential ansi sealed beforefieldinit Draft.Empty
       extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType
{
  .pack 0
  .size 1
} // end of class Draft.Empty
```

As you see it allocates 1 byte at creating time and in the definition the size of this type is 1.

So yes; it allocates 1 byte on stack.

Note: definition of `Empty` extracted from the compiled assembly in release mode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll learn something if you please explain how `new Empty().Equals(new Empty())` returns true. Does it not need an actual address on the stack? (I really am not familiar with JIT workflow); Thanks

Comment: `Equals()` checks value equality for structs. Since there are no fields it is the case that `s1.Equals(s2)` is always `true` for operands of type `EmptyResult`.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian For structs the `Equals` method does a memberwise equals.  All (zero) of the members of those two `Empty` objects are equal, so therefore the two structs are equal.  It's only reference types for which the default equality operator compares the references.

Comment: @Servy Holly Foo! I forgot I am dealing with a value type here!